# Is there a way to communicate between chrome and android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I want to share information from browser using bluetooth but chrome extensions does not have a bluetooth api.So is there a way to send the information from the extension or from the browser itself to the app and use the android apis for bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not insistent on using Bluetooth, why don't you try maintaining a service + DB somewhere and make calls there, that way all of your clients can access the data, they just need to hit the right endpoints?

If you are insistent on using Bluetooth, I know firefox has Bluetooth APIs that let browsers use Bluetooth to connect with devices.